# Server 2008 R2 Backup - 0x8078015b - The Specified Network Name is no longer available

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-backup

This is a really odd one. All of a sudden incremental back-ups using Windows Server Backup are blowing out with '0x8078015b - The Specified Network Name is no longer available.' If I change it to full backup it works fine, but of course takes a long time to complete. Switch back to incremental and the same error after between 1 - 1.5 hours...

Any ideas why incremental would start doing this after running every day for years?

Generally a full backup takes 8-9 hours and incremental less than two

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it doesn't answer the WHY I managed to get it all working again by

1. Carrying out another full backup to the same NAS, new directory - this step because of my paranoia.
2. Delete the original backup.

When the scheduled backup next runs it carries out a full back up, and the next one an incremental.

Given that the same server has backed up every day to the same NAS for nearly five years it will remain a mystery as to why it suddenly decided to throw the toys out of the playpen, but the above got it back on track. Hope this helps someone else if they have the same issue!